Watch command but with shell
I want use shell and see watch on top parallel without switching to another tty.
Is theres way to do that?

This question is similar to: How to split the terminal into more than one "view"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is a bit unclear but, if I understand you correctly, you could do this using tmux.

Start a new session by typing tmux into a terminal.
Split the panel vertically with Ctrl+B+".
In the top pane, run the watch command; in the bottom one, run your other Shell commands.


Similar answer with an example screenshot.
